# Why is queryClient.setQueryData taking so long in this example with react-query?

Tags: reactjs, caching, react-hooks, react-query

I'm updating cache with react-query using useQuery and setQueryData, the problem is setQueryData can take up to 2mins to update the data, possibly due to a loop of some sort. I'm mapping each page on the 'Styles' data, and updating the Styles, Groups and Ranges on the page that matches the pageIndex with data from the response. I have no idea why the very long update, an I using react-query wrong here? The data being updated is not huge at all by the way.

Thanks in advance.

```
export const useStyle = (styleId, pageIndex) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const { refetch } = useQuery('Style', () => fetchStyle(styleId), {
    staleTime: Infinity,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    initialData: {},
    onSuccess: (res) => {
      queryClient.setQueryData('Styles', (oldData) => ({
        pages: map(oldData.pages, (page, index) => ({
          ...page,
          ...(index === pageIndex
            ? {
              Styles: {
                ...page.Styles,
                ...res.Styles,
              },
              Groups: {
                ...page.Groups,
                ...res.Groups,
              },
              Ranges: {
                ...page.Ranges,
                ...res.Ranges,
              },
            }
            : {}),
        })),
        pagesParams: oldData.pageParams,
      }));
    },
  });

  return { refetchStyle: refetch };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem by using useMutation instead of useQuery and setQueryData, this is the better approach if a loop of  onSuccess'es is caused by setQueryData.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're creating an infinite loop here:

- `useQuery('Styles')` subscribes to the key `Styles`, so this component will always update / re-render whenever something in the cache under that key changes
- in `onSuccess` of this query, you update that very same key (`Styles`)
- this update informs all observers, because they should be aware of that change
- calling `setQueryData` *also* triggers `onSuccess`, because `setQueryData` is to be treated the same as if the data came from the backend via the queryFn.
- this will trigger your `onSuccess` again and so on...

The better question would be: What problem are you trying to solve? By the looks of it, you want to perform some data transformation after each fetch. For this, you have multiple options, all of which I have outlined extensively here: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-data-transformations

But usually, merging data like that should not be necessary. The cache should best be a 1:1 mapping of the response you get from the server.

Comment: Hello and thank for the answer, I am trying to fetch a 'Style' and update the cached 'Styles' data, by keeping all of the previous Styles whilst spreading the new Groups, Ranges and Styles into that data. I think a loop is being made indeed, probably on the onSuccess after setQueryData is fired, just cant work it out how to refactor this code.

Comment: i really need a way of calling setQueryData without it calling inSuccess everytime..

Comment: if you have an endpoint that returns one Style, you should keep it in the query cache as just this single style. probably, there should be multiple cache entries, like `['style', styleId]` so that you keep them all cached separately. `styleId` is a dependency to your queryFn so it should definitely be in the key. I don't think you can have an endpoint that only returns one style, but have a cache entry that contains multiple styles.

Comment: I have solved this problem by using useMutation instead of useQuery and setQueryData, this is the better approach if a loop of  onSuccess'es is caused by setQueryData.